# Cypress doesn't trigger Angular form validation after input

Tags: angular, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm trying to test a similar form (in component testing mode):

```
<form [formGroup]="queryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input formControlName="query"/>
    <button [disabled]="!queryForm.valid"/>
</form>
```

with the test code:

```
cy.get('@query').type(queryString, { delay: 50});
cy.get('@submit').should('be.enabled').click();
```

The button works as expected in normal application, but inside Cypress it stays disabled after typing. How can I fix this?
My guess was that the change detection wasn't triggered, but I don't know how to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer looking at [this official example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-component-testing-apps/blob/main/angular/src/app/login-form/login-form.component.cy.ts).
Turns out that I needed to provide some additional configuration like this:

```
const config: MountConfig<QueryInputComponent> = {
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [FormBuilder],
};
it('mounts', () => {
  cy.mount(QueryInputComponent, config);
});
```